# Beta testers finding that StoreKit asks for sandbox environment Apple IDs?

Tags: ios, sandbox, storekit, beta-testing, apple-id

I have been using in-app purchases in my app now for a while. However, my beta testers can't make in-app purchases. I know I should be giving them freebies, because they are helping out, but it concerns me that the beta testers are being asked for sandbox logins. Why would this be happening?

Comment: Because the app isn't in production. The apps downloaded from the app store ask for real ids.

Comment: Got it. I also find that the same is true when running apps from Xcode on my local device. It's usually signed in to my personal apple ID, so I need to log out to use a sandbox ID which is annoying (at the moment I'm testing verifying the receipt and not actually making purchases)